# how to write to a file with Expect and send

Tags: file, command-line, expect, notepad

How do you write to a file using expect, then open in with notepad? I receive results to my command line and I would like to print these results in notepad. Basically an automatic way to get the same result as typing "example.log" into the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control a GUI application with expect. You might need something like [TWAPI](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/) or [TCOM](http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/)

Comment: So it would not be possible to print the results displayed on the command line to a file, then retrieve that information using notepad?

Comment: For example could it be possible to pipe the command prompt output to a file.txt then open the file.txt with notepad

Comment: Yes, expect can write text to a file and then you can pass the filename to notepad as a command line argument. What have you tried?

Comment: Well, more simply, I just want to read what the command prompt displays, and send it to file.txt.

Comment: I haven't tried anything worth noting

Comment: So. use regular expression in your expect commands, use capturing parentheses and extract the relevant information from the `expect_out` array. I highly recommend the [Exploring Expect](http://www.amazon.com/Exploring-Expect-Tcl-based-Automating-Interactive/dp/1565920902) book